# The scope of local variables captured by a lambda function (C++)

Tags: c++, function, lambda, stack, call

I searched everywhere but could not find an answer to my question. I am trying to write an example that shows that capturing a local variable of the enclosing function by reference is dangerous because it may not exist anymore when it is actually referenced. Here's my example:

```
#include <iostream>


std::function<int (int)> test2(int l) {
       int k = 10;
       return [&] (int y) { return ++k + 100; };
}


void test(std::function<int (int)> k) {
        std::cout << k(100);
}

int main() {
        test(test2(100));

        std::function<int (int)> func = test2(100);
        test(func);

        return 0;
}
```

I tried to reproduce stack corruption from trying to access and modify a local variable that doesn't exist on the stack frame by returning a lambda function from *test2* that captures a local variable *k* and modifies it.

```
std::function<int (int)> func = test2(100);
test(func);
```

prints out a garbage value which indicates something went wrong as expected. However,

```
test(test2(100));
```

prints out "111". This is confusing to me as I thought when test2(100) returns a lambda function of type std::function, the stack frame for test2 will be gone, and when test is invoked, it should not be able to access the value of k. I'd appreciate any ideas or keywords I can use to search for answers.

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Accessing `k` after it's gone can do anything, including *not* printing garbage.

Comment: There is no way how to generally detect undefined behavior. Some tools may help in certain situations, such as various types of [clang sanitizers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-code-generation).

Comment: Printing garbage (or crashing) is only a possibility when behaviour is undefined.   It is not guaranteed.  Too many people think that printing garbage or crashing always happen when behaviour is undefined.  Scrub that concept out of your mind, entirely.

Comment: Consistently getting a non-garbage value that indicates that the local variable k may be still accessible means that the compiler (clang++ 3.9 in my case) may be handling two cases differently or it could be a bug. I was thinking about those possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your test on my machine and the results are as expected total garbage in both cases. Having a correct answer once in a while in this capacity is very misleading. A dangling reference or pointer might occasionally point out to the same value as long as the pointed memory hasn't been occupied by a different value yet.

In a nutshell, The C++ lambdas do not extend the lifetimes of captured references/pointers shall their reference stack unwind. Same thing applies to capturing the 'this' pointer of a class. If the class goes out of scope, the 'this->' will result in a completely undefined behaviour.